# Can TBATS be used in the case of deterministic seasonality?

Tags: forecasting, arima, model-selection, seasonality, tbats

I have a monthly dataset which consist of 176 points. I validated that it is stationary by `adf.test` and it has deterministic seasonality by `ch.test`. The test results, time series plot, ACF and PACF plots are shown below:

```r
Warning in adf.test(ts) : p-value smaller than printed p-value

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  ts
Dickey-Fuller = -5.1491, Lag order = 5, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary


    Canova and Hansen test for seasonal stability

data:  ts

      statistic pvalue  
Jan      0.1378 0.4886  
Feb      0.3668  0.092 .
Mar      0.2485 0.2116  
Apr      0.2401 0.2248  
May      0.1674 0.3885  
Jun      0.1745 0.3677  
Jul      0.0541 0.9246  
Aug      0.1059 0.6304  
Sep      0.1084 0.6179  
Oct      0.1546 0.4286  
Nov      0.0565 0.9118  
Dec      0.0828 0.7567  
joint    1.5638 0.4809  
---
Signif. codes: 0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Test type: seasonal dummies 
NW covariance matrix lag order: 14 
First order lag: no 
Other regressors: no  
P-values: based on response surface regressions
```

[image: Time Series Plot]

[image: ACF]
[image: PACF]

Since the ts is already stationary, I did not apply any transformation. Also, I drew the following plots and I saw that it has seasonal pattern.

[image: Seasonal pattern]

```r
ts_model <- tslm(ts ~ season(ts))
summary(ts_model)


Call:
tslm(formula = ts~ season(ts))

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-49.92 -14.04  -4.08  10.82  74.20 

Coefficients:
                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            44.480      5.887   7.556 2.83e-12 ***
season(ts)February   -21.467      8.325  -2.579  0.01080 *  
season(ts)March      -11.967      8.325  -1.437  0.15250    
season(ts)April      -19.173      8.325  -2.303  0.02253 *  
season(ts)May        -10.547      8.325  -1.267  0.20700    
season(ts)June        -9.027      8.325  -1.084  0.27983    
season(ts)July       -40.373      8.325  -4.850 2.87e-06 ***
season(ts)August     -38.323      8.472  -4.523 1.17e-05 ***
season(ts)September  -27.951      8.472  -3.299  0.00119 ** 
season(ts)October    -13.680      8.472  -1.615  0.10831    
season(ts)November   -11.009      8.472  -1.299  0.19565    
season(ts)December     6.241      8.472   0.737  0.46236
```

How can I use the linear model above for time series analysis. As you see there is deterministic seasonality but according to regression results, some parameters are insignificant.

To be honest, I get very confused about this topic time to time. In the case of deterministic seasonality, how should we determine the model if the data is stationary? As far as I understand so far, this can be done by adding `xreg` to the `auto.arima` function. `auto.arima` function gave me ARIMA(0,0,0) as a best model. Can I apply TBATS in this case?